# Ubuntu VM just shows a black screen with blinking cursor when setting up

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

It has 2 CPUs, and also has 3d graphics checked, and it has VMSVGA selected as a graphics controller, but despite all this it still shows a black screen with blinking cursor. How do I fix this? I haven't installed Ubuntu in the machine yet.
Also, I have a Mac OS host.

Comment: In settings, did you increase video memory to its maximum of 128MB? Did you turn 3d acceleration off? Both in the VM, not the host.

Comment: @Bib I did those but the problem's still persisting...

Comment: What is the source of the Ubuntu image? What version?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik 22.04.3